# How to show only the last 4 degits of a creditcard

Tags: php, html

'xx' is a number ( credit card number with 16 number ) i need to show only the last 4 degits, someone can help me please

example : `xx = 9999999999991234`
`(value='9999999999991234') = (value='***********1234')`

```
<li>
    <div class="sectionValue" id='xxxxxxxx' value='<?echo $xx; ?>' </div>
</li>
```

Comment: `substr()` seems like it might be useful here.  Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Treat the CC as a string, then it's just simple string operations. rip off last 4 digits and display, fill the rest with `*`.

Comment: Please do this in PHP. If you do it on the client your site will not be secure in the slightest. I've edited the JS tags out of the question for this reason.

Comment: Definitely don't do this in JavaScript (it is trivial to see the whole number). Depending on your local regulations it might not even be permitted for you to _store_ the entire thing. _Any_ direct handling of credit card data should make you _very uneasy_. Services like [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) exist for a reason.

Comment: If you are holding credit card numbers.... then I sincerely hope that you are fully PCI compliant, itherwise you're opening yourself up to heavy-duty lawsuits.... and if you're PCI compliant, then you should know how to do something as fundamentally basic as this..... so better stop storing those credit card details, or prepare to be sued for large sums of damages and/or fines

Comment: Your starter on [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/)

Comment: Don't worry guys i now that is not secure and there is options like stripe, im just learning and thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may simply use a combination of `substr()` and `str_replace()`

```
<?php
    function getTruncatedCCNumber($ccNum){
        return str_replace(range(0,9), "*", substr($ccNum, 0, -4)) .  substr($ccNum, -4);
    }
?>

 <div class="sectionValue" id='account_changed' > 
     <?php echo getTruncatedCCNumber($ccNum); ?> 
 </div>
```

Or use a non-efficient `preg_replace()`:

```
    $ccNum          = "9999999999991234";
    $last4Digits    = preg_replace( "#(.*?)(\d{4})$#", "$2", $ccNum);
    $firstDigits    = preg_replace( "#(.*?)(\d{4})$#", "$1", $ccNum);
    $ccX            = preg_replace("#(\d)#", "*", $firstDigits);
    $ccX           .= $last4Digits;

    var_dump($firstDigits);    //<== '999999999999' (length=12)
    var_dump($last4Digits);    //<== '1234' (length=4)

    var_dump($ccX);            //<== '************1234' (length=16)
```

To display this in a div, do like so:

```
<?php

    $ccNum          = "9999999999991234";
    function getTruncatedCCNumber($ccNum){
        $last4Digits    = preg_replace( "#(.*?)(\d{4})$#", "$2", $ccNum);
        $firstDigits    = preg_replace( "#(.*?)(\d{4})$#", "$1", $ccNum);
        return preg_replace("#(\d)#", "*", $firstDigits) . $last4Digits;
    }

?>

 <div class="sectionValue" id='account_changed' > 
     <?php echo getTruncatedCCNumber($ccNum); ?> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Please tell me how can i let that work in div like that <div class="sectionValue" id='account_changed' > <?echo $ccnumber; ?> </div>

Comment: @haillucker you already asked this question bellow my post and I answered it 9 minutes ago!

Comment: @Poiz Thanks alot for everything , it wored perfectly THANK YOUUUU !

Comment: @haillucker    Good! You may as well check this as the right answer. It's another way to express gratitude & motivate the contributor and acts as a visual cue to visitors with similar issues... so they can see at a glance which answer solved the Problem.

Comment: Why the regular expressions? [`substr`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is going to be _much_ more efficient…

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative value with stbstr to start from the right side.

```
<?php
$var = '1234567890';
echo '***********' . substr($var,-4);
?>
```

Comment: Please tell me how can i let that work in div like that <div class="sectionValue" id='account_changed' > <?echo $ccnumber; ?> </div>

Answer (score 0):

**Don't Try This at Home**

```
value = '9999999999991234';
// convert string to array
var array = value.split("");
// define the new string
var newValue = '';

// loop through the array
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

  if(i<12) {
    // for the first 12 digits add a 'x'
    newValue += 'x';
  } else {
    // for the last 4 digits add the digit
    newValue += array[i];
  }

}
```

**Better way: PHP**

```
<?php

$value = '9999999999991234';
$array = str_split($value);
$newValue = '';

for ($i=0; $i < ; $i++) {

  if(i<12) {
    // for the first 12 digits add a 'x'
    $newValue .= 'x';
  } else {
    // for the last 4 digits add the digit
    $newValue +. array[i];
  }

}

echo '(value=' . $newValue . ')';
```

If you want to echo the variable inside HTML:

```
<div><? echo $newValue; ?></div>
```

Comment: A JavaScript solution might work for display purposes, but it doesn't obscure the number in a secure way. Seeing the entire thing will be trivial.

Comment: How can i let the  xx poste in the ( value='' ) like automatically is value='<?echo $xx; ?>'; gonna work ?

Comment: My answer was in JS not in PHP. What are you asking?

Comment: @haillucker I would do all the manipulation on the php side and as you stated just echo it into the value field (after it has been obscured on php side). I hope that makes sense

Comment: Please tell me how can i let that work in div like that <div class="sectionValue" id='account_changed' > <?echo $ccnumber; ?> </div>

Comment: Yes that's it, echo the PHP variable inside the HTML code: `<div class="sectionValue" id='account_changed' ><? echo $ccnumber; ?></div>`

Comment: @Ivan THANK YOUU alote for everything

Answer (score 0):

Similar as other responses but wrapped in a function
I prepared this solution on the php side as this will be more secure and not expose CC info to client side (javascript)

```
function ccMask($cc, $fillChar='*'){

    $last4= substr(str_replace(['-',' '],'',$cc), -4);
    return str_pad($last4, 16, $fillChar, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo ccMask($cc);
echo ccMask($cc, '#');//you can pass in a different character if you like
echo ccMask('5421 5678 9012 9876', '#');//output ############9876
```

This method will also allow you to pass in credit card numbers with or without the hyphens or spaces

Comment: Please tell me how can i let that work in div like that <div class="sectionValue" id='account_changed' > <?echo $ccnumber; ?> </div>

Comment: well if you have your ccnumber (the whole cc number) as a php variable then you could simply wrap the call to the function in an html block
<?php $ccnumber = '1234567890123456'; ?> <div class="sectionValue" id='account_changed' > <?php echo ccmask($ccnumber); ?></div>